# Docker: Download all from nltk in Dockerfile

Tags: python, docker, nltk

How would I achieve the following in a Dockerfile:

```
sudo python
import nltk
nltk.download('all')
```

Comment: `sudo python -c 'import nltk; nltk.download("all")'`?

Comment: Well, I am a newbie to docker, but I was wondering if it is possible to ship the these nltk resources while building the container to the image?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can build a custom Docker image with everything you need:

```
FROM python:3.6-slim
RUN pip3 install nltk
RUN [ "python", "-c", "import nltk; nltk.download('all')" ]
ENTRYPOINT python
```

Then build:

```
docker build -t docker-nltk .
```

And run:

```
docker run -it docker-nltk
```

Comment: great answer! Just like to ask something a little off-topic. Did you try whether the python3.6 installs and runs properly within the docker? That'll help us in tackling this issue: https://github.com/nltk/nltk/issues/1659

Answer (score 2):

If you add your code to the file downloadall.py this Dockerfile does the job on my machine:

```
FROM python:3
RUN pip install nltk
ADD downloadall.py /
CMD [ "python", "./downloadall.py" ]
```

Let me know if it works for you!

Comment: Nice solution @rmeertens

Answer (score 0):

This is how to do it properly:

```
FROM python:3.7

RUN pip install nltk
RUN python -m nltk.downloader all

...rest of Dockerfile...
```